Getting duplicates when saving an item with two fields in a many-to-many relationship
I'm working on an online shop project. In the project I have a model named Product which has a many to many relationship with a model named Color by a Product-Color model. I want to add a property named Quantity to Product-Color for every Color I add. I use Razor Page and .net 8.
This is what I've done.
This is the view :
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Colors</label>
     @{
         var colors = ViewData["Colors"] as List<Color>;
     }
     @foreach (Color color in colors)
     {
         <div>
             <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedColors" value="@color.ColorId"/>@color.ColorName
             <div>
                 <label>تعداد</label>
                 <input type="number" name="ColorQuantities" class="form-control" />
             </div>
             <hr/>
         </div>
     }
 </div>

This is code behind:
 public IActionResult OnPost(IFormFile imgProductUp, List<int> SelectedColors, List<int>? ColorQuantities)
 {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return Page();
     }

     int productId = _productService.AddProduct(Product, imgProductUp);
     _productService.AddColorToProductByAdmin(productId, SelectedColors, ColorQuantities);
     return RedirectToPage("Index");
 }

This is service :
   public void AddColorToProductByAdmin(int productId, List<int>? SelectedColor, List<int>? ColorQuantities)
   {
       foreach (int color in SelectedColor)
       {
           foreach (int quantity in ColorQuantities)
           {
               _context.ProductColors.Add(new ProductColor()
               {
                   ProductId = productId,
                   ColorId = color,
                   Quantity = quantity
               });
           }
       }
       _context.SaveChanges();
   }

I want to assign property "Quantity" to selected ColorId in Product-Color table, but my codes make two loops.
This is what I get in my database:

There is a loop for colorId list and a loop for quantity list. I just want to know how can I send quantity list and prevent the repetition of colorId list twice while adding quantity list.
So I need guidance on how to solve this issue.

You are looping over the three colours, then for each colour you add all three quantities. Assuming the two lists are aligned with each other, using a single for loop will do what you want:
public void AddColorToProductByAdmin(int productId, List<int>? SelectedColor, List<int>? ColorQuantities)
{
    if (SelectedColor is null)
        return; // there are no colors

    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedColor.Count; i++)
    {
        _context.ProductColors.Add(new ProductColor()
        {
            ProductId = productId,
            ColorId = SelectedColor[i],
            Quantity = ColorQuantities?[i]
        });
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}


Tank you so much. It worked
